# Kotlin coroutines barrier: Wait for all coroutines to finish

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I need to start many coroutines in a for loop and get a callback in the Main thread after all the tasks are completed.

What is the best way to do this?

```
//Main thread
fun foo(){
    messageRepo.getMessages().forEach {message->
       GlobalScope.launch {
            doHardWork(message)
       }
    }
   // here I need some callback to the Main thread that all work is done.
}
```

And there is no variant to iterate messages in CoroutineScope. The iteration must be done in the Main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wait until all tasks will be completed with `awaitAll` and then execute your callback in the main thread with `withContext`

```
fun foo() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        messageRepo.getMessages().map { message ->
            viewModelScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                doHardWork(message)
            }
        }.awaitAll()
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            // here I need some callback that all work is done.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in your code iteration is not in the main thread.

Comment: @DmitriyPuchkov sorry, I've missed this point. Now it's fixed

Comment: Please update your answer to async(Dispatchers.IO), because in case async(Dispatchers.Main) doHardWork executed in Main thread

Comment: @DmitriyPuchkov sure. Another misunderstanding :)